# urllib getting HTML but missing data

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib2

Right basically I'm getting and displaying HTML which displays the data I'm looking for just fine in a normal browser but not in a HTML dump with urllib.

Example URL: https://betfred.mobi/sports/horses/event/4315034.2

Example data: Horse names like "She Is No Lady"

Displays just fine under a browser. Doesn't need any login or preexisting cookies or anything.

I thought maybe it was waiting to see an actual user agent or something but that should be fine as well. I'm setting one and I've checked - it's working.

```
opener = urllib2.build_opener()
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.124 Safari/537.36')]
response = opener.open("https://betfred.mobi/sports/horses/event/4315034.2")
print response.read()
```

It's showing something alright and I'm getting a HTML dump of the site but horse names for example are not showing up.

Am I missing something blindingly obvious here?

Comment: Yep, you did miss something. Data is loaded after the page has loaded via Javascript. Either you automate your scraping using a browser-like process (Mechanize or Selenium), or intercept the data itself. I see a JSON file containing their names and stats. You can request that instead and get the data right away. The URL construction is a bit difficult though.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to handle pages with Javascript, try [WATIR](http://watir.com/) or [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/) - those drive a real web browser, and can thus handle any Javascript. WATIR Classic requires either IE or Firefox with a certain extension installed, and you will see the pages flash on the screen as it works.

At present, Mechanize doesn't handle JavaScript.

Your other option would be understanding what the Javascript on the offending page does and bypassing it manually, but that seems onerous.